# Locale not working on linux server

Tags: php, linux, locale

I am trying to get local language of the current machine for that i use the following code

```
$currentLocal = setlocale(LC_CTYPE, null);
echo $currentLocal;
```

it returns the value correctly in **localhost/windows**, but in linux server it was not working on live it returns only **C** any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `C`, otherwise known as the `POSIX`, locale, supports only 7-bit ASCII characters.  Read more here: [POSIX Locale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_02).  And here: [What does “LC_ALL=C” do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do)

Comment: so wats the solution?

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: getting output as "C" on linux server but not in localhost, it returns the value correctly

Comment: Like I said in the answer, `C` is a valid locale.

Comment: There really is no language name.

Comment: then what is in it really?